# FreeImageNET TIFF conevertion error

Tags: c#, .net, freeimage

We have some TIFF files and we want to convert it to JPEG.
We try to use FreeImageNET wrapper to FreeImage library.
In C# we have code:

```
dib = FreeImage.Load(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_TIFF, path, FREE_IMAGE_LOAD_FLAGS.DEFAULT);
```

TIFF image load Ok, no errors here.
But if we want to save image by code:

```
FreeImage.Save(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_JPEG, dib, Path.Combine(newPathForSave, fsh.GetNextFileName() + ".jpeg"), FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.DEFAULT);
```

No errors here but jpeg file size is zero. Why ?

Comment: Which version of FreeImage and FreeImageNET you use?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try changing the Flag of the JPEG to something like FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.JPEG_QUALITYGOOD

Check the library documentation:
[SAVE_FLAGS](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/fnet/html/E77CD483.htm)

I am using the same library to save a bmp as a TIFF and is the only thing I can see from my code that is different.